# Redirect and post to external url in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How we can redirect and post data form a controller to external URL in AngularJS?
i want to use this method to send secure my data.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var projectService = angular.module('projectServices', ['ngResource']);

projectService.factory('modulename', ['$http', 'conFig', 
    function($http, conFig) {

        var dataFactory = {};

        dataFactory.postdata = function (data) {
            return $http.post('URL', data);
        };
        return dataFactory;
    }]);
```